# How do I display prompt once

Tags: javascript, laravel, frontend

I am trying to make this function be one time for each user upon the conditions met, I want each user to only see this message once and never again

```
function pdfZero(){
                var fileName = "myDocument.pdf";
                var fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop("pdf");
                var balance = document.getElementById("userBal");
                if ( balance = '0.00$' && fileExtension){
                    
               return confirm('This is a complimentary free translation of your document for a first page only. Add money to order an entire document.'); 
    }
    }
```

Comment: How/when are you calling this function?

Comment: Save this fact per user server side and then don't show it - store/expose that fact when you render and detect if from wherever that is in the rendered content

Comment: @evolutionxbox <button id="upload_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="pdfZero();">UPLOAD</button>

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss could you please give me an example?

Comment: @CharlesAnnan It really depends on the type of persistence you are looking for here, you can save the user's choice in either `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, as a cookie, or in a database.

Comment: You DO know (well probably NOT;) that you have bugs here `var balance = document.getElementById("userBal");
                if ( balance = '0.00$' && fileExtension){` where you assign balance the value in the conditional check and thus overwrite it's reference to that element (which you never actually checked for any monetary or otherwise value.) We would need more including perhaps the rendered HTML to best help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable at the top of your code flagging whether or not a prompt has been sent

```
var hasBeenAsked = false;
```

and later

```
confirm(_____);
hasBeenAsked = true;
```

Alternatively, if you want it to only ask even *after* a page refresh, you can store something in session/local storage. Session storage will disappear after a browser restart, local will remain.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("hasAsked", 1)
sessionStorage.getItem("hasAsked")
```

With either of these methods, you can add an if statement to check the value of the flag, and only call the confirm() function if it is false.

Comment: It's also important to note that JavaScript is easily modifiable in the browser, and if you are demanding payment for more than one translation, you may need to do this part server-side. A simple incognito browser will bypass any checks here that you save client-side, and anyone who knows their way around an Inspect panel can easily edit any code.

Comment: Thank you very much @letsdothisEpic I'll keep it in mind but it's more like I'm trying to make a one time offer for the user, so I'll need it to appear once and never again, even if they come back another time